# Issue with webservice result schema in Webexperience Factory

Tags: websphere-portal

I'm using **IBM webexperience factory 8.0.** with fixpack. In my project I'm using **Webservice Multiple Operations** builder. It is having different operations with different result schema. When I try to assign the result of an operation to a Datapage it is showing the same result schema for all the operations.

Actually the return values of these operations should be different but it is showing the same.

Please refer this link for the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I solve this issue.